# How to access nested array values in JSON response and use them in a loop in next service in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am working on a POST service that give JSON response. 
I have to extract certain value from the JSON response. example-

```
`{
  "Result":
   {  "Id":22
      "StartTime":
      "EndTime":
      "RoutePoints": 
            [{ "Id":675,
             }
             { "Id":676,
             }
            ]
  } 
}    `
```

My first part of the question- 
How do I refer the "Id" variable inside the "RoutePoint" array using regular expression extractor? I can simply use "Id", but I also have an "Id" variable outside the "RoutePoint" array.

Secondly- 
How do I take the "Id" each time and run them in a loop in the following service? Example- I take "Id=675" and perform a job, then take "Id=676" and perform that same job. Please be as detailed as possible, I am new to JMeter.

Comment: you don't parse json with regexes. you decode it to a native data structure, and access it like you would any other native data structure.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific. Earlier I have parsed JSON response and have used "regular expression extractor" to extract values from the response and used in it in POST request bodies for later services.

Comment: Would be easier if you posted the entire JSON. Having said that, I suggest using JSON path extractor (http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Path_PostProcessor) - it's built-in in JMeter 3, and can be downloaded as plug-in in earlier versions (http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/).

Comment: @KirilS. I have edited my post to give a clearer idea of the response. I need to access the "Id" which has numbers 675 and 676.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend going for [JSON Path PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Path_PostProcessor) which is available since JMeter 3.0

Add JSON Path PostProcessor as a child of the request which returns above JSON and configure it as follows:

- Variable Names: anything meaningful, i.e. `Id`
- JSON Path Expressions: `$..RoutePoints.*.Id`
- Match Numbers: `-1`

You should get variables like:

```
Id_1=675
Id_2=676
Id_matchNr=2
```

suitable for iteration with i.e. [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller)

Demo:

[image: JSON Path Extractor]

References:

- [JSONPath - XPath for JSON](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/)
- [Advanced Usage of the JSON Path Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped.